# how to use instanceof to differentiate two javascript classes implement same interface in unit test

Tags: javascript

I have two classes which implement same interface. Let's say:
class A implements X
Class B implements X

if I create object type A and B, a = new A(), b = new B(). then
a instanceof A is true
a instanceof B is true

Is there way to test the difference between a and b?

Thanks

Comment: [tag:javascript] doesn't have interfaces. Do you mean [tag:typescript]?

Comment: `if I create object type A and B, a = new A(), b = new B(). then a instanceof A is true a instanceof B is true` - that shouldn't be correct, `a instanceof B` should be `false` unless there's something else going on. Please show us the actual code.